# Internet Explorer Rendering Issues. (HTML CSS JS)

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I have been trying to build a search engine using HTML and CSS and JS, but IE11 just doesn't seem to like text boxes. The dropdown items overlap the text field and is never displayed properly (Screenshot attached).Works fine in google Chrome and Edge. But NEVER works in IE11. That said, java script renders super slow too

Any help would be Highly appreciated.

[CODEPENLINK](https://codepen.io/jasonpraful/pen/QWwOYNL)

Image 1 - Internet Explorer

Image 2 - Google Chrome

```js
var testVals = ["What are your primary job responsibilitiasasasasases?",
    "What experience did you have to get your job?",
    "How long have you worked here?",
    "What is your own background and experience?",
    "What is a typical work day like?",
    "How long is your work day?",
    "How much variety is there in your work?",
    ];

$(document).ready(function () {
    elementList = document.getElementById("testListDummy");
    //Search Box Function
    $(".search-text").on("input", function () {
        if ($('.search-text').val() == '') {
            $('.search-text').removeAttr('style');
            elementList.innerHTML = " ";
        } else {
            $(".search-text").css({"width": "350px", "padding": "0 6px"});
            var a="";
            a = $(".search-text").val().toUpperCase();
            a.replace(/[_\s]/gi, "").toUpperCase();
            console.log(a);

            var entry = document.createElement('li');
            var arrayVal = ""
            elementList.innerHTML = " ";
            for(i=0;i<=testVals.length;i++){
                arrayVal = testVals[i].toUpperCase();
                if(arrayVal.includes(a)){
                    console.log(testVals[i])
                    $('#testListDummy').append('<li>'+testVals[i]+'</li>');
                    console.log(document.getElementById('testListDummy'));


                }


            }



        }
    });

});
```

```css
.search-box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 260px;
    left: 46%;

    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background: #2f3640;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.search-box:hover > .search-text {
    width: 350px;
    padding: 0 6px;

}

.search-box:hover > .search-btn {
    background: white;

}

.search-btn {
    color: #e84118;
    float: right;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #2f3640;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    transition: 1s;

}

.search-text {
    font-family: VFRegular;
    border: none;
    background: none;
    outline: none;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    transition: 0.5s;
    line-height: 40px;
    width: 0px;
 height: 50px;


}


.search-box > ul {
    left: -100px;
    background-color: #2f3640;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 15px;


}

.search-box > ul li {
    left: -10px;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
 width: 90%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    z-index: 1;
}

.search-box > ul li:last-child {
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}


.search-box > ul li:hover {
 font-weight: bold;
 
}
```

```html
<!-- Search Box -->
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css">
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.10.1/css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- JQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.4/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.10.1/js/mdb.min.js"></script>
  
  
  
  
  
  
</head>
<body>
  <div class="entire-searchbox">
    <div class="search-box">
        <input class="search-text" type="text" placeholder="Type to search">

        <a class="search-btn" href="#">
            <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
        </a>

        <ul id="testListDummy">
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

[image: IMAGE IN IE]

[image: Image in Chrome]

Comment: IE is dead now, Edge is the new IE, , if you are working at a company, then tell them dont use IE, as Microsoft don't give support for it and also its vulnerable to hacks

Comment: tried but they dont seem to budge, need a quick fix for this issue

Comment: if you really want to fix it, try inspect it in ie and same time in chrome, and see which styles are messing up, i tried to open your codepen on IE and they also don't allow it

Comment: at my work I dont solve there issue if they have it on IE, detect the browser and 
 put a "Unsupported Browser " message at main screen,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There're two issues in your code. First, `includes` is not defined in IE. You need to [add polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#Polyfill) to make it supported in IE 11. Second, you need to give a `width` value to `.search-box` to make it have a correct width in IE when animation. You could add these two lines in your script:

```
if ($('.search-text').val() == '') {
                ...
                $('.search-box').removeAttr('style');
                ...
            } else {
                ...
                $(".search-box").css({ "width": "410px" });
                ...
            }
```

The code sample is like below:

```js
//polyfill for includes
if (!String.prototype.includes) {
  String.prototype.includes = function(search, start) {
    'use strict';

    if (search instanceof RegExp) {
      throw TypeError('first argument must not be a RegExp');
    }
    if (start === undefined) {
      start = 0;
    }
    return this.indexOf(search, start) !== -1;
  };
}

var testVals = ["What are your primary job responsibilitiasasasasases?",
  "What experience did you have to get your job?",
  "How long have you worked here?",
  "What is your own background and experience?",
  "What is a typical work day like?",
  "How long is your work day?",
  "How much variety is there in your work?",
];

$(document).ready(function() {
  elementList = document.getElementById("testListDummy");
  //Search Box Function
  $(".search-text").on("input", function() {
    if ($('.search-text').val() == '') {
      $('.search-text').removeAttr('style');
      $('.search-box').removeAttr('style');
      elementList.innerHTML = " ";
    } else {
      $(".search-text").css({
        "width": "350px",
        "padding": "0 6px"
      });
      $(".search-box").css({
        "width": "410px"
      });
      var a = "";
      a = $(".search-text").val().toUpperCase();
      a.replace(/[_\s]/gi, "").toUpperCase();
      console.log(a);

      var entry = document.createElement('li');
      var arrayVal = ""
      elementList.innerHTML = " ";
      for (i = 0; i <= testVals.length; i++) {
        arrayVal = testVals[i].toUpperCase();
        if (arrayVal.includes(a)) {
          console.log(testVals[i])
          $('#testListDummy').append('<li>' + testVals[i] + '</li>');
          console.log(document.getElementById('testListDummy'));
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.search-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 260px;
  left: 46%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #2f3640;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.search-box:hover>.search-text {
  width: 350px;
  padding: 0 6px;
}

.search-box:hover>.search-btn {
  background: white;
}

.search-btn {
  color: #e84118;
  float: right;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #2f3640;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 1s;
}

.search-text {
  font-family: VFRegular;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  outline: none;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  line-height: 40px;
  width: 0px;
  height: 50px;
}

.search-box>ul {
  left: -100px;
  background-color: #2f3640;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.search-box>ul li {
  left: -10px;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  width: 90%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  z-index: 1;
}

.search-box>ul li:last-child {
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}

.search-box>ul li:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css">
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.10.1/css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- JQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.4/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.10.1/js/mdb.min.js"></script>
<div class="entire-searchbox">
  <div class="search-box">
    <input class="search-text" type="text" placeholder="Type to search">
    <a class="search-btn" href="#">
      <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
    </a>
    <ul id="testListDummy"></ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @JasonFrancis you could mark it as an answer if it has solved your issue.